# Adding new items in an existing list in MS Sharepoint using REST?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I'm still a beginner in Javascript and was assigned to create a one page survey form in our sharepoint site. I made one with multiple textboxes and dropdowns. Now my next goal is to pass the values from these fields to an existing list called "Feedback".

I tried researching and still don't get some of the codes for it. I have the backbone code but i don't know how can i pass the values from my textboxes/dropdowns. Here is my current code:

```
    var value1 = document.getElementById("recipient_dropdown").value;
    var value2 = document.getElementById("name_textbox").value;
    var webUrl = "https://sharepoint.ap.sample.com/phl/SIL-BA/BAC";

    // occurs when a user clicks the create button
    function CreateNew() {
        var listName = "Feedback";
        var newItemTitle = "";
        CreateListItemWithDetails(listName, webUrl, newItemTitle, function () {
            alert("New Item has been created successfully.");
     }, function () {
         alert("Ooops, an error occured. Please try again.");
     });
    }

    function CreateListItemWithDetails(listName, webUrl, newItemTitle, success, failure) {
            var item = {
            '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.customlistListItem' },
            'Title': newItemTitle,
            'Addressed_x0020_To': value1,
            'Individual_x0020_Name': value2             
        };


        $.ajax({
            url: webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Feedback')/items",
            method: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            data: JSON.stringify(item),
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

In this sample, i want to add the values from the 2 variables (value1 and value2) into the existing list called "Feedback" from the url "https://sharepoint.ap.sample.com/phl/SIL-BA/BAC".

I am receiving an alert message when i click the button but it returns a "Obj obj" message.

Also in the console page, it returns an "Error 400 Bad Request" from the line: webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Feedback')/items"

Can you guide me how can i do it with my current code? I would also appreciate if you can explain some of it so i can understand it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The `__metadata` is wrong, suppose your list is Feedback, the `__metadata` should be `SP.Data.FeedbackListItem`.

[image]

Update:

My sample test result with fiddler.

Code reference here:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operation-on-list-items-using-rest-api-services-in-shar/

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried changing the metadata but it still has the same result.